# Get MSB / LSB in register

Tags: assembly, arm

This might seem like a stupid question, but I cant really tell what I'm missing

On ARM 7:

I have a 8 digit number in register 0, say

```
10110111
```

I want to 'loop' through this and do something with the current bit until the 8 bits are up, but I'm having alot of trouble with this simple issue..

My logic is:

```
- get MSB / LSB of number in r0
- shift it to r1
- lsl / lsr r0
```

But from this logic, I dont know how you would get the MSB / LSB. Could anyone help me out? Or is there a better way of looping through this?

Thank you!

Comment: what are you trying to do?  simply examine each bits state or are you counting ones or something? flipping the order of the bits?

Comment: You could also us an array of masks 1, 2, 4, 8,16... Loop though and do an AND on the register value.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the `rbit` and `clz` instructions. These allow you to compute the MSB and LSB index.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a hard time understanding your issue. But if you shift with flags LSLS you can read the carrybit and it from there.

Comment: Sorry, as you can tell I'm pretty new to assembly. Thanks for your help! You're saying if i do LSLS it will go to the carry bit? Reading from the carry bit would be to get irt from a certain spot from the xPSR register right?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a workaround to this issue, but I'm not sure it's the best method.

Solution:

Use a 2nd register with value 1, with every iteration, AND (r0,r1) thats your bit. Then just LSL r1, and continue.

eg

```
mov r0, #0b10101010 @original
mov r1, #1

loop:
    and r2,r0,r1 @this is your bit
    lsl r1
    b loop
```